# Do I need to caulk at the bottom of where the siding meets the concrete?

Tags: concrete, caulking

I am putting vinyl siding down to a concrete foundation.  Do I need to caulk where the siding meets the concrete?

Comment: Think you would want the bottom not sealed, so any moisture behind the siding can drain/escape away.

Answer (score 1):

There is normally a track that goes on the bottom that the siding fits into. It isn't supposed to be caulked or sealed in normal installations so moisture can escape.